# Postgres cascade delete doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, parent-child, cascade

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    brand VARCHAR(100),
    model VARCHAR(100),
    transmission VARCHAR(50),
    engine REAL,
    year INTEGER
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE ads(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR(500),
price INTEGER,
sold BOOLEAN,
create_date TIMESTAMP,
car_id INTEGER REFERENCES cars(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I delete some ad like

```
delete from ads where id=1;
```

it works fine - and deletes, but the appropriate car doesn't delete. Why? 
I didn't find proper answer in the web. Thanks for expected help.

Comment: `on delete cascade` works the opposite way - when referenced column's value gets deleted, it cascades to referencing, sweeping on orphains

Answer (score 2):

`on delete cascade` works the opposite way - when referenced column's value gets deleted, it cascades to referencing, sweeping on orphans. The other way around does not make much sense - if you don't allow cars with no referencing ads, you can't insert even the first row, meanwhile FK on ads.car_id won't allow insert before you add a car.

Which leads to conclusion that you need either some job that will check for lonely parents (cars with no ads) and remove them, or add some trigger that will check on ads delete, if `select count(1) = 0 from cars where id = OLD.car_id` then `delete from cars where id = OLD.car_id`, this way you will be able to insert car with no ads, but as soon as ads appear, don't keep cars with no ads.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I have messed parent and child. Now it is clear.